# How to determine which text classification algorithm is most appropriate for a given problem?

Tags: classification, modeling, natural-language

As someone very new to NLP, I'm curious to know what types of things people consider before building text classification models to help determine an appropriate starting point.

For example, I see people may use a GRU or an LSTM, but are there any questions to consider **before** training any models that might inform whether I should expect either the GRU or LSTM to be the more appropriate model?

When attempting to look online for guidance, I see lots of [articles like this](https://towardsdatascience.com/model-selection-in-text-classification-ac13eedf6146), where the approach is to just train dozens of models and pick which performs best. And not that this is invalid, but I'd like to be a bit more intentional if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb is: the more difficult the classification is for you as a human being, the more complex model you would need.

1. Can you guess the label from the presence of few keywords? → If yes, it is probably enough to use a BoW representation (e.g., TF-IDF) and your favorite traditional ML algorithm.
2. Can you guess the label from the words in the sentence, but it seems it would be hard to come up with a list of keywords? → If yes, word embeddings (probably without stopwords) + your favorite traditional ML algorithm or a feed-forward neural net should be enough.
3. Can you guess the label the presence of few word phrases, and and need to be aware of simple negations? → If yes, word embeddings (pre-trained or not) + [convolutional classifier](https://aclanthology.org/D14-1181/) will be a good choice.
4. Do you need the structure of the sentence (know who is the subject, who does what, etc.) to assign the label correctly? → If yes, do some serious deep learning.

Currently, the best choice is the pre-trained Transformers (such as BERT or RoBERTa). Their main advantage is that fine-tuning requires much less training data than training the models from scratch, which you would probably need to in the case of RNNs.

Comment: Super helpful -- when you say "serious deep learning" is that then where you are referring to transformers/RNNs, or would there be other methods as well to consider?

Comment: No, I meant Transformers and RNNs.